# Ruby/Rails - issues with JSON.parse/JSON.decode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

My controller receives a JSON string inside params which looks like following:

`{"serialized"=>"{\"key\":{\"subkey1\":"value",\"subkey2\":"value"}"}`

In my controller I try the following:

```
JSON.parse(params[:serialized], symbolize_names: true)
```

Which returns:

```
{:"key"=>{:subkey1=>"value", :subkey2=>"value"}
```

All the nested subkeys were symbolized; the key was symbolized in a weird way so it is not responding to **hash[key]**, but does to **hash["key"]**.

If I go through the Rails stack:

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:serialized]).symbolize_keys
```

I get back the following:

```
{:"key"=>{"subkey1"=>"value", "subkey2"=>"value"}
```

Almost same as the first one except for nested keys; they are not being symbolized.

I've even tried looping through hash trying to symbolize the keys manually; with no success though:

```
Hash[params[:serialized]{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v] }] # returns {:"key"=>{"subkey1"=>"value", "subkey2"=>"value2"}
```

Why is this happening? Why is the key symbolized as **:"key"** instead of **:key**?

**UPD**
Removed last line (How could I possibly fix that since I need my hash to answer to **hash[key]** and not **hash["key"]**.) so the question looks less pragmatic and more theoretic.

Comment: FWIW `:key == :"key" #=> true`

Comment: Why are you expecting `hash[key]` instead of `hash[:key]` to be possible?

Comment: @sawa I'd say it's rather unimportant; more important is why is it happening?

Answer (score 2):

try on rails console.

```
require 'json'
string = {"serialized"=>"{\"key\":{\"subkey1\":"value",\"subkey2\":"value"}"}
hash = JSON.parse string
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what @boulder said above. But since, `Hash[params[:serialized].symbolized_keys.map{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v.symbolize_keys] }]` is for symbolizing till 1 level. I won't really go for this, ever.

This is probably different from what you are asking for, but accessing hash's key/values in Rails, is usually suited like `hash.key` instead of `hash[:key]` or `hash['key']`.
This is the primary convention, and is the reason, how one can access fields like `@user.name` etc.

Rails implements this by [`OpenStruct`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/classes/OpenStruct.html). To use it, you can do:

```
@foo = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(params[:serialized]).symbolize_keys
obj = OpenStruct.new(@foo)
obj.key #=> {"subkey1"=>"value", "subkey2"=>"value"}
```

But again, OpenStruct creates the object till one level for accessing with `.key` instead of ':key'. To aid this, we have [Recursive OpenStruct](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct), which does the job perfectly.

This is the way, I personally feel, you should work in Rails in scenario like this(if arrives).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, :key and :"key" are two ways to express the exact same thing. In fact if you do:

```
> :key == :"key" 
=> true
```

so given a hash such as

```
h = {:"key" => "value"}
h[:key]
=> "value"
```

Secondly, if you have nested hashes, you don't only want to symbolize the keys manually, you also want to symbolize the keys in the values

```
Hash[params[:serialized].symbolized_keys.map{ |k, v| [k.to_sym, v.symbolize_keys] }]
```

Of course, you need something more elaborate if you have more than one level of 'nestesness'

Comment: The manual altering of keys was there just as an example. I know that :key == :"key". I've asked why is this happening; i.e. half of keys are converted to :key and the other half is converted to :"key". symbolize_keys just calls VARIABLE.to_sym which evaluates into :VARIABLE. So where is the magic happening?

Comment: I see, I understood your question as being more pragmatic, since you end with ' How could I possibly fix that since I need my hash to answer to hash[key] and not hash["key"]'? To answer your question, you'll get the :"key" notation when you're creating symbols that cannot be represented using the :xxx notation. For example `"key\ ".to_sym` returns `:"key "` while `"key".to_sym` returns `:key`

Comment: Yes, thats correct - "key\ " returns :"key " but notice the space there; In first case there was no space returned in :"key:

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but for those that might fall on it, Rails provides the method `deep_symbolize_keys` that seems to do exactly what op needs after parsing json :

```
hash = { 'person' => { 'name' => 'Rob', 'age' => '28' } }

hash.deep_symbolize_keys
# => {:person=>{:name=>"Rob", :age=>"28"}}
```

Source: https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/deep_symbolize_keys